# "AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute set" tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter.optionmenu

I am getting an error that says this when I am trying to use an OptionMenu in tkinter. This is the error:

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'set'

The code:

```
from tkinter import *
w = Tk()
w.geometry("250x250")
w.title("OptionMenu Testing")
def DoNothing():
    pass
options = ["Option1", "Option2", "Option3"]
DropdownMenuVar = StringVar()
DropdownMenuVar.set("Option1")
DropdownMenu = OptionMenu(w, DoNothing, *options)
DropdownMenu.place(x=175, y=200)
```

I can see the options, but when I click on one, it does that!
This code is just a test script for another script that involves `OptionMenu`s.

EDIT: Just removed the function parameter, now I am getting this:
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'set'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
DropdownMenu = OptionMenu(w, DoNothing, *options)
```

Should be like this:

```
DropdownMenu = OptionMenu(w, DropdownMenuVar, *options)
```

Unrelated, but I highly recommend you use PEP8 style names. It makes your code much easier to read.